# A function to detect common passwords and prevent user from setting it?

Tags: javascript, security, passwords

I'm working on user passwords security and one of the important things for me is to force the user to reenter a password when the password is found in most common passwords list.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Disclaimer: I do not know the answer, but... there are several readymade components for password strength evaluation : http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/10-password-strength-meter-scripts-for-a-better-registration-interface/ In case you cannot use them, you can surely browse the implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. You can create a text-file with common passwords and check if the password a user entert is in this list.

One big drawback is that this file would be very large and it is nearly impossible to cover all common passwords this way.

So I would recommend to write a function which checks the user input for different forbidden phrases. For e.g. if you know the real names of the users I would forbid to take them as a part of a password. In addition you can force the user to enter a minimum amount of characters as well as some special characters or numbers.

Comment: Nice idea but I already did this to prevent a user to set the password that would be his username for example, or fullname! But I also came up with making a small function to prevent a user from entering common password. It works fine!

Answer (score 3):

I came up to this method and it's working fine. It detects 500 most common passwords. Returning 'true' if there is an entry of blacklisted password in the password field.

I hope it will help someone.

```
function passwordPreventCommon(commonValue) {

var commonPassword = Array("123456","password","12345678","1234","pussy","12345","dragon","qwerty","696969","mustang","letmein","baseball","master","michael","football","shadow","monkey","abc123","pass","6969","jordan","harley","ranger","iwantu","jennifer","hunter","2000","test","batman","trustno1","thomas","tigger","robert","access","love","buster","1234567","soccer","hockey","killer","george","sexy","andrew","charlie","superman","asshole","dallas","jessica","panties","pepper","1111","austin","william","daniel","golfer","summer","heather","hammer","yankees","joshua","maggie","biteme","enter","ashley","thunder","cowboy","silver","richard","orange","merlin","michelle","corvette","bigdog","cheese","matthew","121212","patrick","martin","freedom","ginger","blowjob","nicole","sparky","yellow","camaro","secret","dick","falcon","taylor","111111","131313","123123","bitch","hello","scooter","please","","porsche","guitar","chelsea","black","diamond","nascar","jackson","cameron","654321","computer","amanda","wizard","xxxxxxxx","money","phoenix","mickey","bailey","knight","iceman","tigers","purple","andrea","horny","dakota","aaaaaa","player","sunshine","morgan","starwars","boomer","cowboys","edward","charles","girls","booboo","coffee","xxxxxx","bulldog","ncc1701","rabbit","peanut","john","johnny","gandalf","spanky","winter","brandy","compaq","carlos","tennis","james","mike","brandon","fender","anthony","blowme","ferrari","cookie","chicken","maverick","chicago","joseph","diablo","sexsex","hardcore","666666","willie","welcome","chris","panther","yamaha","justin","banana","driver","marine","angels","fishing","david","maddog","hooters","wilson","butthead","dennis","captain","bigdick","chester","smokey","xavier","steven","viking","snoopy","blue","eagles","winner","samantha","house","miller","flower","jack","firebird","butter","united","turtle","steelers","tiffany","zxcvbn","tomcat","golf","bond007","bear","tiger","doctor","gateway","gators","angel","junior","thx1138","porno","badboy","debbie","spider","melissa","booger","1212","flyers","fish","porn","matrix","teens","scooby","jason","walter","cumshot","boston","braves","yankee","lover","barney","victor","tucker","princess","mercedes","5150","doggie","zzzzzz","gunner","horney","bubba","2112","fred","johnson","xxxxx","tits","member","boobs","donald","bigdaddy","bronco","penis","voyager","rangers","birdie","trouble","white","topgun","bigtits","bitches","green","super","qazwsx","magic","lakers","rachel","slayer","scott","2222","asdf","video","london","7777","marlboro","srinivas","internet","action","carter","jasper","monster","teresa","jeremy","11111111","bill","crystal","peter","pussies","cock","beer","rocket","theman","oliver","prince","beach","amateur","7777777","muffin","redsox","star","testing","shannon","murphy","frank","hannah","dave","eagle1","11111","mother","nathan","raiders","steve","forever","angela","viper","ou812","jake","lovers","suckit","gregory","buddy","whatever","young","nicholas","lucky","helpme","jackie","monica","midnight","college","baby","brian","mark","startrek","sierra","leather","232323","4444","beavis","bigcock","happy","sophie","ladies","naughty","giants","booty","blonde","golden","0","fire","sandra","pookie","packers","einstein","dolphins","0","chevy","winston","warrior","sammy","slut","8675309","zxcvbnm","nipples","power","victoria","asdfgh","vagina","toyota","travis","hotdog","paris","rock","xxxx","extreme","redskins","erotic","dirty","ford","freddy","arsenal","access14","wolf","nipple","iloveyou","alex","florida","eric","legend","movie","success","rosebud","jaguar","great","cool","cooper","1313","scorpio","mountain","madison","987654","brazil","lauren","japan","naked","squirt","stars","apple","alexis","aaaa","bonnie","peaches","jasmine","kevin","matt","qwertyui","danielle","beaver","4321","4128","runner","swimming","dolphin","gordon","casper","stupid","shit","saturn","gemini","apples","august","3333","canada","blazer","cumming","hunting","kitty","rainbow","112233","arthur","cream","calvin","shaved","surfer","samson","kelly","paul","mine","king","racing","5555","eagle","hentai","newyork","little","redwings","smith","sticky","cocacola","animal","broncos","private","skippy","marvin","blondes","enjoy","girl","apollo","parker","qwert","time","sydney","women","voodoo","magnum","juice","abgrtyu","777777","dreams","maxwell","music","rush2112","russia","scorpion","rebecca","tester","mistress","phantom","billy","6666","albert");

for (var i=0; i < commonPassword.length; i++) {

    if (commonPassword[i]===commonValue) {
        return true;
    }    
};
return false;
};
```

Before you include it somewhere test it with simple alert:

```
alert(passwordPreventCommon('password'));
```

As the word 'password' is blacklisted it will alert 'true'.

---

**Edit:** Iteration part can be replaced with [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method from ES6:

```
if (commonPassword.includes(commonValue)) {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: You really should use property lookup, not iterating over 500 elements. Not only it is much faster, it makes check take just one line instead of entire function.

Comment: How did you obtain the list of blacklisted passwords?

Comment: That was some time ago. I don't remember exactly how.

Answer (score 2):

There is Nist Bad Passwords (NBP) project with a JS library for checking if a password is one of the common used passwords. Check this: https://cry.github.io/nbp/

Answer (score 1):

A slight variation of Ilia Rostovtsev's answer (as I can't post it as a comment).

While I'm not saying looping through an array is the fastest way, this is slightly faster due to not checking the array length each time the loop runs, and it also uses ES2015 syntax.

```
const isPasswordCommon = (userPassword) => {

    const commonPassword = Array("123456","password","12345678","1234","pussy","12345","dragon","qwerty","696969","mustang","letmein","baseball","master","michael","football","shadow","monkey","abc123","pass","6969","jordan","harley","ranger","iwantu","jennifer","hunter","2000","test","batman","trustno1","thomas","tigger","robert","access","love","buster","1234567","soccer","hockey","killer","george","sexy","andrew","charlie","superman","asshole","dallas","jessica","panties","pepper","1111","austin","william","daniel","golfer","summer","heather","hammer","yankees","joshua","maggie","biteme","enter","ashley","thunder","cowboy","silver","richard","orange","merlin","michelle","corvette","bigdog","cheese","matthew","121212","patrick","martin","freedom","ginger","blowjob","nicole","sparky","yellow","camaro","secret","dick","falcon","taylor","111111","131313","123123","bitch","hello","scooter","please","","porsche","guitar","chelsea","black","diamond","nascar","jackson","cameron","654321","computer","amanda","wizard","xxxxxxxx","money","phoenix","mickey","bailey","knight","iceman","tigers","purple","andrea","horny","dakota","aaaaaa","player","sunshine","morgan","starwars","boomer","cowboys","edward","charles","girls","booboo","coffee","xxxxxx","bulldog","ncc1701","rabbit","peanut","john","johnny","gandalf","spanky","winter","brandy","compaq","carlos","tennis","james","mike","brandon","fender","anthony","blowme","ferrari","cookie","chicken","maverick","chicago","joseph","diablo","sexsex","hardcore","666666","willie","welcome","chris","panther","yamaha","justin","banana","driver","marine","angels","fishing","david","maddog","hooters","wilson","butthead","dennis","captain","bigdick","chester","smokey","xavier","steven","viking","snoopy","blue","eagles","winner","samantha","house","miller","flower","jack","firebird","butter","united","turtle","steelers","tiffany","zxcvbn","tomcat","golf","bond007","bear","tiger","doctor","gateway","gators","angel","junior","thx1138","porno","badboy","debbie","spider","melissa","booger","1212","flyers","fish","porn","matrix","teens","scooby","jason","walter","cumshot","boston","braves","yankee","lover","barney","victor","tucker","princess","mercedes","5150","doggie","zzzzzz","gunner","horney","bubba","2112","fred","johnson","xxxxx","tits","member","boobs","donald","bigdaddy","bronco","penis","voyager","rangers","birdie","trouble","white","topgun","bigtits","bitches","green","super","qazwsx","magic","lakers","rachel","slayer","scott","2222","asdf","video","london","7777","marlboro","srinivas","internet","action","carter","jasper","monster","teresa","jeremy","11111111","bill","crystal","peter","pussies","cock","beer","rocket","theman","oliver","prince","beach","amateur","7777777","muffin","redsox","star","testing","shannon","murphy","frank","hannah","dave","eagle1","11111","mother","nathan","raiders","steve","forever","angela","viper","ou812","jake","lovers","suckit","gregory","buddy","whatever","young","nicholas","lucky","helpme","jackie","monica","midnight","college","baby","brian","mark","startrek","sierra","leather","232323","4444","beavis","bigcock","happy","sophie","ladies","naughty","giants","booty","blonde","golden","0","fire","sandra","pookie","packers","einstein","dolphins","0","chevy","winston","warrior","sammy","slut","8675309","zxcvbnm","nipples","power","victoria","asdfgh","vagina","toyota","travis","hotdog","paris","rock","xxxx","extreme","redskins","erotic","dirty","ford","freddy","arsenal","access14","wolf","nipple","iloveyou","alex","florida","eric","legend","movie","success","rosebud","jaguar","great","cool","cooper","1313","scorpio","mountain","madison","987654","brazil","lauren","japan","naked","squirt","stars","apple","alexis","aaaa","bonnie","peaches","jasmine","kevin","matt","qwertyui","danielle","beaver","4321","4128","runner","swimming","dolphin","gordon","casper","stupid","shit","saturn","gemini","apples","august","3333","canada","blazer","cumming","hunting","kitty","rainbow","112233","arthur","cream","calvin","shaved","surfer","samson","kelly","paul","mine","king","racing","5555","eagle","hentai","newyork","little","redwings","smith","sticky","cocacola","animal","broncos","private","skippy","marvin","blondes","enjoy","girl","apollo","parker","qwert","time","sydney","women","voodoo","magnum","juice","abgrtyu","777777","dreams","maxwell","music","rush2112","russia","scorpion","rebecca","tester","mistress","phantom","billy","6666","albert");

    const commonPasswordLength = commonPassword.length;

    for (var i=0; i < commonPasswordLength; i++) {

        if (commonPassword[i] === userPassword) {
            return true;
        }    
    };

    return false;
};
```

https://codepen.io/andrethedrummer1/pen/GdobPa