# I need the submit button to enable when the passwords match. (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I have a script to automatically tell people when their new passwords match (account activation) but I need to find a way to get it to enable the submit button as well.

Here is my code:

JS:

```
function checkPasswordMatch() {
    var password = $("#new_password").val();
    var confirmPassword = $("#new_password2").val();

    if (password != confirmPassword) $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("<font color=\"red\"><b>Check Passwords</b></font>");
    else $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("<font color=\"green\"><b>Passwords Match</b></font>");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#txtConfirmPassword").keyup(checkPasswordMatch);
});​
```

HTML

```
<table>
    <form action="activate_account.php" method="post">
        <tr>
            <td align="right">
                <label for="new_password">Password (6-12 chars):</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="password" name="new_password" id="new_password" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">
                <label for="new_password2">Again:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="password" name="new_password2" id="new_password2" onkeyup="checkPasswordMatch();"
                />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <td>
                    <div class="registrationFormAlert" id="divCheckPasswordMatch"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="submit">
                        <input type="submit" value="Activate Account" disabled="disabled" />
                    </div>
                </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I know it's wrong, I'm just trying to get this thing functional before I clean it up.

Comment: Just updated my answer for you, please take a look at it below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must do this:

```
$("#buttonActivate").prop("disabled", false);  // to enable the button
```

Afterwards don't forget to use this code, if a user decides to change the password again, so your button would get inactive again

```
 $("#buttonActivate").prop("disabled", true); // to disablethe button
```

Just replace your current code with this one but *don't forget to update HTML as well*:

### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function checkPasswordMatch() {
    var password = $("#new_password").val();
    var confirmPassword = $("#new_password2").val();

    if (password != confirmPassword) {
        $("#new_password").css("background", "red");
        $("#new_password2").css("background", "red");
        $("#buttonActivate").prop("disabled", true);
        return false;
    } else {
        $("#new_password").css("background", "green");
        $("#new_password2").css("background", "green");
        $("#buttonActivate").prop("disabled", false);
        return true;
    }
}
  $("input").keydown(function() {
    var password = $("#new_password").val();
    var confirmPassword = $("#new_password2").val();
    if (password.length >= 6 && confirmPassword.length >= 6) {  // let's check if the password is >= 6 otherwise there is nothing to check
        checkPasswordMatch();
    }
});
```

See updated HTML in the example below:

1. Set an ID to your `<form>`, let's say `id="accountActivation"`;
2. Change your `input` button to `button` and set an id to it as well:
   `<button id="buttonActivate" type="submit" disabled="disabled">Activate Account</button>`

### [jsFiddle Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/965mG/)

[Updated jsFiddle to show `Passwords mismatch` warning](http://jsfiddle.net/965mG/1/)

I believe it will work for you right!

Comment: You are very welcome! You would also be probably interested in Preventing Common Passwords, take a look at my post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11780249/a-function-to-detect-common-passwords-and-prevent-user-from-setting-it/11790303#11790303 Don't forget to double check everything on the server side. We never  rely on client side! Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for changing attribute

```
$("input[type=submit]").removeAttr("disabled");
```

See .removeAttr [Here](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

Answer (score 0):

Give your submit button an id:

```
<input id="activateAccountButton" type="submit" value="Activate Account" disabled="disabled" />
```

Then in your check passwords function add:

```
function checkPasswordMatch() {
    var password = $("#new_password").val();
    var confirmPassword = $("#new_password2").val();

    if (password != confirmPassword)
        $("#acivateAccountButton").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("<font color=\"red\"><b>Check Passwords</b></font>");
    else
        $("#acivateAccountButton").removeAttr("disabled"); 
        $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("<font color=\"green\"><b>Passwords Match</b></font>");

}
```

Also make sure you have validation on the server side!!!

Answer (score 0):

To add on to PoX's answer, if you are using **jQuery 1.6** or later, you should use the `prop()` method for setting *enabled* and *disabled* states:

```
$("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", false);
```